# How do you upload multiple files with AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, afnetworking

I can upload a single file without any issues but now I find that I need to upload 1 or more files, does anyone know how to do this with AFNetworking?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a multipartFormRequest

```
NSURLRequest* request = [[YourHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                         path:path
                         parameters:dict
                         constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                              [formData appendPartWithFileData:data1
                                                          name:@"image1"
                                                          fileName:@"image1.jpg"
                                                          mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                              [formData appendPartWithFileData:data2
                                                          name:@"image2"
                                                          fileName:@"image2.jpg"
                                                          mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                         }
                     }];
```

Comment: (I know this's old) As a side note, if you want to upload an array of files, the name can be set as `imaage[]`

Comment: Question! what if I want to keep track the progress of each file ?

Comment: @AsifHabib, Create a dedicated request for each file.

Comment: does this scale though? Suppose I have 20 gb worth of images?