# ARC Issue: No known instance method for selector 'appendPartWithFileData:mimeType:name:'

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, afnetworking

When following the `AFNetworking` example to upload a form:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        keyField.text, @"key",
                        valField.text, @"val",
                        nil];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

NSURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" 
                                                          path:@"/upload" 
                                                    parameters:params 
                                     constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                                         [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData 
                                                                 mimeType:@"image/png" 
                                                                     name:@"avatar"];
                                     }];
```

Compilation returns error:

```
ARC Issue: No known instance method for selector 'appendPartWithFileData:mimeType:name:'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bit strange that the compiler considers this an “ARC issue”. IMHO the `AFMultipartFormData` protocol doesn’t contain a method called `appendPartWithFileData:mimeType:name:`. Take a look at the documentation, maybe the protocol was refactored and the method signature change a bit. I’m not sure where does `AFMultipartFormData` come from, but a short search gave me [these docs](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Protocols/AFMultipartFormData.html) that suggest you might have success with `appendPartWithFileData:name:fileName:mimeType:`.

Comment: `appendPartWithFileData` is in `AFHTTPClient.h`.

Comment: With the correct signature? All versions of the header I have found contain just the longer version with name, file name and MIME. Are you looking at the same header as your compiler?

Comment: It's an ARC issue because without ARC, calling selectors the compiler doesn't know about is fine. As long as someone implements the selector, even at runtime, there's no problem. You get a warning. But with ARC, the compiler needs to see the prototype for the method to see if there are any `__autoreleasing` or other attributes attached to it to determine the mechanics of how it should be called. Without seeing those rules, the compiler calls it an error instead.

Comment: Aha, thanks, that makes sense. I always set the compiler to treat warnings as errors, so for me calling unknown selectors is already an error, ARC or not. That’s why I considered the error message weird.

Answer (score 1):

The signature in my AFHTTPClient.h looks like this:

```
- (void)appendPartWithFileData:name:fileName:mimeType:
```

and matches the documentation [here](http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Protocols/AFMultipartFormData.html#//api/name/appendPartWithFileData:name:fileName:mimeType:). Could just be that the sample is outdated.

Update: See this [SO answer: How do you upload multiple files with AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559075/how-do-you-upload-multiple-files-with-afnetworking)