# iOs Multiples Files upload with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, file-upload, afnetworking

I'm using AFnetworking for my iPhone project, i'm a beginner in Objective C.

I know how to upload multiples files using blocks, as describes here :
[How do you upload multiple files with AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559075/how-do-you-upload-multiple-files-with-afnetworking)

So into the block, we can add as many formData elements as we want.

But in my case, i do not know how many pictures i will have, since the user is free to select many. The picture's data is store into an array.

So i tried something like that into the block, but only the last element is uploaded :

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in imagesInfo) {

      UIImage *theFile = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
      NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theFile, 0.5);
     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"name" fileName:@"name.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

}
```

Anyway, i was able to get it working by launching another request when the first one has finished. 
But i guess there is a best way to get it working ?

Tanks a lot,

Rodolphe

Comment: Have you tried varying the name and filename per attachment?

Answer (score 3):

AFNetworking has a couple of nice utilities for managing a "batch" of requests. There are 3 methods in particular you should consider from the AFHTTPClient class:

enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests  //for batches
enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations  //for batches
enqueueHTTPRequestOperation  //for single request

Basically, you would loop through your array of photos and build a new array of NSMutableURLRequest (s) (pretty much like you are probably doing now). For each photo, create either a NSMutuableURLRequest or a HTTPRequestOperation and pop it in the array.  The pass the new array of HTTP URL requests to AFNetworking using one of the mentioned methods.

If you want to manage the upload process as a batch use one of the batching methods.  If you just want to fire and forget, use the enqueueHTTPRequestOperation which still gives you all the AFNetworking happiness.

It looks something like this:

```
AFHTTPClient *photoUploader = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] init];
[photoUploader enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:self.photosWrappedInNSURLS   progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

    //block gets called after each succesful operation
    //useful for messages like 1 of 3 complete

} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {

    //block gets called after all requests are complete
}];
```

if you read the doc's they will suggest you make your own subclass of AFHTTPClient and construct it as a singleton.  You don't have to use it that way, but it is very handy if you have more than one type of connection back to the same host or service.  I found it very useful in my last project and had very good success with it.

hope that helps
be well

Answer (score 0):

Try ASIHTTPRequest library. Using this library you can download/upload multiple files simultaneously or one by one: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: I read this as "If you're not sure how to do this with a modern library, you should instead figure out how to do it with a deprecated one." That's terrible advice.

Comment: Many people still use this "deprecated" library in their projects. It works just fine with all versions of iOS available now.

Comment: Be that as it may, the question indicates they're already using a library and want to know how to work with it. Again, telling them to figure out how to do it with a **different** and unsupported library isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a different name for each file. I suspect that will fix it.