# How to upload multiple images from iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image-uploading, whatsapp

I am developing an app where I am trying acheive uploading of good quality multiples images to server, method I am following is:

```
1. Selecting N images on the iOS app
2. I inform server about the N images, inturn server creates N urls in amazon and return it to iOS app
3. I do a PUT call to upload images one by one to amazon from iOS app.
4. After uploading N images, I make a call to server with all the successful uploads URL.
```

Problem with this synchronous approach is it involves N + 2 calls(not including retry for all the failed uploads) and also its takes lot of time in case if there are multiple images. also

Could you direct me to the efficient **approach to upload multiple images parallely so that it saves timing something like whatsapp** multiple images uploads?
Thanks.

Comment: AFNetworking do that. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559075/how-do-you-upload-multiple-files-with-afnetworking.

Comment: If I have around 10-15 HD images to upload, I don't think this is the most efficient method to use, its going to make huge request..

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. One questions first :
The requests for the urls, They are specific to each photo ( have GUID) ?

If not , you can record to all requests asynchronously , and as the the answers are coming  you will calling the method of uploading files to the URLs you've ever have. The AFNetworking is a good tool because it already makes requests asynchronously , so you need not be dealing with send and return.